# Make 8.1 notifications vibrate more like 8.0

Tags: 8.1, vibration

Ever since updating to 8.1, I've had a hard time telling the difference between an e-mail notification and an SMS notification without actually having to look at the phone. Since I never use ringtones, the only indicator I've had in the past was the vibration pattern - an e-mail would vibrate twice and a text would vibrate once. After the update though, it seems every notification vibrates only once.

Is there any way to restore the old behavior without rolling back?

Comment: I never noticed that the email notification would vibrate differently to sms. Have you tried turning vibrate off completely for email, then after a few smses have come through, turn it off for sms and on for email? Just to make sure that it is following this pattern.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, my vibrate pattern is different for emails and SMS

Comment: This seems fixed after I transitioned from 8.1 Developer Preview on Black, to 8.1 on Cyan. May have been a DP/Black bug. I'll close this after I have more time to verify for sure.

Comment: After some tweaking around with the phone, it looks like changing the ringtone breaks the "fixed" state. Not sure how they're attached to the vibration yet, and still pretty sure there's not an option to change the vibe independently.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this was a problem either with the Developer Preview version of Windows Phone 8.1, or its use in conjunction with the Lumia Black firmware for my Nokia Lumia 920. After doing a system restoration to Lumia Cyan with Windows 8.1 (Preview for Developers not installed), the vibrations I'm used to have been restored - single for SMS, double for e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

NO , you have to use different notification sounds if you want the privilege of not looking the phone.